# iOS App crashes on ICMPushNotificationManager classesToSwizzle

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, crashlytics

I am getting crashlogs on crashlytics about number of my users are facing this crash but i couldn't be able to found the solution. If any one can help that will be greatful below are stack trace i am getting on crashlytics

```html
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x239559dd0 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x239553924 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2395538c0 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 26
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x238b97478 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 112
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x238b973d0 __objc_error + 38
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x238ba4218 class_conformsToProtocol + 448
6  GrocerApp                      0x100bd102c +[ICMPushNotificationManager classesToSwizzle] + 1366376
7  GrocerApp                      0x100bd02a0 +[ICMPushNotificationManager swizzlePushNotificationClasses] + 1362908
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x2393fd7d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x2393a0eb8 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
10 GrocerApp                      0x100bd0230 +[ICMPushNotificationManager swizzleReceiveRemoteNotifications] + 1362796
11 GrocerApp                      0x100b7bf18 +[ICMBridge registerDeviceToken:] + 1017940
12 GrocerApp                      0x100421574 specialized AppDelegate.application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:) + 4308604276 (<compiler-generated>:4308604276)
13 GrocerApp                      0x10041d310 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:) + 4308587280 (<compiler-generated>:4308587280)
14 GrocerApp                      0x100c2f8a4 -[OneSignalAppDelegate oneSignalDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications:deviceToken:] + 1753568
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x2393fca38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x2393fd7d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x2393ab008 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068
18 CoreFoundation                 0x239950b20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
19 CoreFoundation                 0x23994ba58 __CFRunLoopRun + 1924
20 CoreFoundation                 0x23994afb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
21 GraphicsServices               0x23bb4c79c GSEventRunModal + 104
22 UIKitCore                      0x2661acc38 UIApplicationMain + 212
23 GrocerApp                      0x100397fd0 main + 29 (AppDelegate.swift:29)
24 libdyld.dylib                  0x23940e8e0 start + 4
```

Comment: Move to intercom version 2.1.1, looks like its fixed in later version.

Comment: i am already using 5.5.2

Comment: was this ever solved? i'm still seeing it on version 8.0.0